# DotNetNuke 6: AD Forms-based Authentication to Dynamics AX 2009 Business Connector

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

There are 2 parts to this question.  To develop applications with ASP.NET that interface with AX 2009, calls to the Business Connector (BusinessConnectorNet.dll) must make a call through the Axapta object like this:

```
Axapta ax = new Axapta();
ax.LogonAs("ad_username", "domain.com", new NetworkCredential("ad_username",
    "ad_password", "domain.com"), null, null, null, null);
```

The obvious problem is that the unencrypted/unhashed password is expected to passed in from a login form.  This would have already been done by the user on either the DotNetNuke or EasyAD module we purchased (both SqlMembershipProvider based).

The desired result is a single sign-on solution with DotNetNuke 6.

Here is the question:

**Is there a recommended solution to obtaining and passing on the unencrypted password, or is there some hidden undocumented Membership methods built-in to the BusinessConnector?**

Note: My experience levels are:

- DotNetNuke 6: Beginner (Have made and installed working modules)

  ASP.Net: Intermediate

  C#: Advanced

  AX 2009: Intermediate

  Business Connector: Intermediate

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a recommended solution to obtaining and passing on the
>   unencrypted password

You don't do this forward the encrypted ( actually hashed ) password instead.

> is there some hidden undocumented Membership methods built-in to the
>   BusinessConnector?

Unlikely.  This is better left up to ASP.NET

I don't understand the problem to be honest.  Your approach seems an intial attempt and it seems you simply stopped there.  There really isn't any code I can provide since you asked `Yes` and `No` questions.

Comment: The gist is this: I don't _want_ to capture the password, for security reasons, but the Business Connector for AX isn't a MembershipProvider friendly piece of code.  It *expects* a plain-text password to be coming in for it's own exposed login procedure.  How's this for a follow-up question: *Any ideas for how I can work around this?*